# Как по vnc подключиться к телефону с другого устройства?

Tags: android, linux, консоль, vnc

На телефоне установлена программа userland. С помощью этой программы установлен debian на телефон. Запускаю там vncserver. Вот команда: ┌──(userland㉿localhost)-[~]
└─$ vncserver

New 'X' desktop is localhost:1

Starting applications specified in /home/userland/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/userland/.vnc/localhost:1.log
Вопрос: как мне подключитья к этому vnc серверу с другого устройства, которое находится в одной локальной сети с телефоном и подключено к роутеру по wifi?
Пробовал в настройках realvnc viewer указать ip телефона и порт 5901, не подключается.

Пробовал ping с планшета на телефон и наоборот. Пинг не проходит. Destination Host unreachable.

Когда создаю точку доступа на телефоне, подключаюсь к ней с планшета, то vnc подключается нормально.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках роутера стояла "изоляция беспроводных устройств". Отключил и всё заработало.